# sed + search word with strings and replaced all word

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to create with `sed` the following:

For example each word in the file that have the `ssss...`
Should be replaced (all word) with target string as `gggg`.

```
echo "duwdbnhb ssssssmnfkejfnei" | sed s'/ssssss*/gggg/g'
duwdbnhb ggggmnfkejfnei
```

should be:

```
duwdbnhb gggg
```

remark - string could be with couple of `s` strings ( for example `ss` or `sss` or `ssssss` ...)

Example:

```
echo "duwdbnhb sssmnfkejfnei" | sed s'/s*/gggg/g'
duwdbnhb gggg
```

example A

```
echo "rf3 f34kf3ein3e ssghdwydgeug swswww ssswjdbuyhb" |  sed s'/ss.*/gggg/'

rf3 f34kf3ein3e gggg
```

but should print that:

```
rf3 f34kf3ein3e gggg swswww gggg
```

example B

```
echo "rf3 f34kf3ein3e ssghdwydgeug swswww ssswjdbuyhb" |  sed s'/s.*/gggg/'

rf3 f34kf3ein3e gggg
```

but should print that:

```
rf3 f34kf3ein3e gggg gggg gggg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to replace the each word beginning with 2 or more `s`-characters:

```
sed s'/ss[^[:blank:]]*/gggg/g'
```

Comment: see my update question

Comment: @yael See my updated answer

Comment: From the word beginning `\<ss[^[:blank:]]*` or `\bss\S*`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sed -r 's/(^|[[:blank:]])(ss[^[:blank:]]*)/\1gggg/g' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% echo "rf3 f34kf3ein3e ssghdwydgeug swswww ssswjdbuyhb" | sed -r 's/(^|[[:blank:]])(ss[^[:blank:]]*)/\1gggg/g' 
rf3 f34kf3ein3e gggg swswww gggg
```